# Unable to restart a DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

We're using Spring 4.3.1, and are getting messages from a queue using the following bean:

```
    @Bean(name="listenerContainer")
public SprMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() throws JMSException, SQLException {
    SprMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new SprMessageListenerContainer();
    listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory((ConnectionFactory) connectionFactory());
    listenerContainer.setMessageListener(messageListener());
    listenerContainer.setSessionTransacted(true);
    listenerContainer.setCacheLevel(0);
    listenerContainer.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(3);
    listenerContainer.setDestinationName("ourQueue");
    // (April 2017): we provide the possibility to manually stop/start the listner container > autostart needs to be set to false, otherwise we can only stop the container, but not restart it anymore
    //                   see: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractJmsListeningContainer.html#setAutoStartup-boolean-
    listenerContainer.setTransactionManager(jmsTransactionManager());
    listenerContainer.setAutoStartup(false);
    listenerContainer.start();
    Assert.isTrue(listenerContainer.isRunning());
    return listenerContainer;
}

@Bean(name="connectionFactory")
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException, SQLException {
    return AQjmsFactory.getConnectionFactory(dataSourceConfig.gpDataSourceAdapter());
}

    private JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager() throws JMSException, SQLException {
    JmsTransactionManager transactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

SprMessageListenerContainer is:

```
public class SprMessageListenerContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer {

@Override
protected MessageConsumer createConsumer(Session session, Destination destination) throws JMSException {
    return ((AQjmsSession) session).createConsumer(destination, null, new SprORADataFactory(), null, false);
}

@Override
protected void doShutdown() throws JMSException {
    logger.info("Shutting done."); 
}
```

}

In our application, we correctly get a reference to our listenerContainer bean. When the application start, the listener is correctly started, and we see message getting processed.

In our code, as soon as we do:

```
listenerContainer.shutdown();
```

Then, no message will be processed anymore > expected.

But, further in our code, we do:

```
listenerContainer.start();
```

We would expect messages to be processed again, but it's not the case, nothing happen (we also don't get any exception and/or error).

Is something wrongly configured in our bean? What could be missing in order to manually stop/start our container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... answering myself ... what was missing was a call to afterPropertiesSet() method.

Comment: You could also use `stop()` instead of `shutdown()`.